# Why I can't override configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nhibernate

I'm doing tutorial [NHibernate - Override Configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_override_configuration.htm) step by step, but unfortunately I'm struggling with an error in last line in **Program.cs**:

> "The format of the initialization string does not match the specification starting with index 0."

Going deeper in error:

```
   in System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   in System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   in NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   in NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
   in NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
   in NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   in NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   in NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   in NHibernateDataTypesMapping.Program.Main(String[] args) w C:\...\NHibernateLab\NHibernateDataTypesMapping\Program.cs:line 29
```

---

**Program.cs**:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x => {
                x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
            });
            cfg.Configure();
            var sefact = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.connection_string">default</property>
    <!--<property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
      Initial Catalog=NHibernateLabDB;
      Integrated Security=True;
      Connect Timeout=30;
      Encrypt=False;
      TrustServerCertificate=False;
      ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
      MultiSubnetFailover=False
    </property>-->

    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>
    <mapping assembly="NHibernateDataTypesMapping"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**App.config**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=NHibernateLabDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I'm using property that contain connection string in **hibernate.cfg.xml** everything working fine, I can working on db, but when I'm trying to use connection string in **App.config** I'm getting an error. 
I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here

[3.4. NHibernate provided ADO.NET connection](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc)

> `connection.connection_string`     Connection string to use to obtain the connection.
>   `connection.connection_string_name` The name of the connection string *(defined in `<connectionStrings>` configuration file element)* to use to obtain the connection.

... different key/name in this case. I.e. instead of that:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">default</property>
```

we need this:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string_name">default</property>
```